# Redirect from checkout/cart to same page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, redirect

In the cart screen, I've included a block that is calling a controller, where I modify the items of the cart, and after this, I want to reload the cart screen again, so I can see the changes in the quantities and prices.

But the redirect method is doing nothing.

This is my controller:

```
class MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            ...
            try {
                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    $item->setQty(2);
                }
                $cart->save();
                $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_item_complete',
                    array('item' => $item, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
                );
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot update shopping cart.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        }
    }

    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }
}
```

The line:

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: use `return $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');`

Comment: the same... I've also added `return $this;` at the end, but same thing... no redirecting

Comment: Can you debug that it executes `_redirect` function ? Also your controller name `MyModule_IndexController` seems wrong, it should be `MyCompany_MyModule_IndexController`

Comment: The module name was changed on purpose, don't worry. That controller is called from an Ajax method, sgo I'm oing to return something like this `echo json_encode(array('reload' => $reload_url, ...));` and handle the redirection through JS code.

Comment: ahh!!. If you are calling this method by AJAX (not mentioned in question), then echo return url and use `window.location.href` to redirect by javascript

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you'll need to put redirect code right before last closing "}". Because if your request is not POST type - you'll have no redirect at all.

And instead of

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

You can try to use these constructions:

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

or

```
$redirectUrl = $this->getUrl('checkout/cart');
$this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl);
```